# sftp ssh key permissions

Tags: ssh, sftp, sublimetext3, sublime-text-plugin

I am using Sublime Text 3's sftp addon. When I try to sync my files I get an error that says:

> The permissions on your SSH private key allow it to be read by other users and consequently the "sftp" command line program will not use it.
>   Please change the permissions so the file is not world readable. For more detailed help, open your terminal and execute the following:
>   /usr/bin/sftp -C -oPort=6922 -oConnectTimeout=30 -oIdentityFile=~(private ssh key location)

When I type what it says in the terminal I get a bunch of information that I don't quite understand.

How do I fix this issue?

Comment: You want your private key to have readonly permissions only for you. Usually your private key is located in the .ssh directory in your home folder (~/.ssh). Often it will have the default name id_rsa. You can try chmod 400 ~/.ssh/id_rsa

Answer (score 1):

In terminal, use the below command :

```
$ chmod 700 your_file.pem
```